# Java based oAuth API to connect to Twitter

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to use oAuth in order to login to my website (with a Twitter account). The backend of the website will be created using Java and the front end will be created using JSP/JSF. Is there any Java based stable API that i could use to connect to Twitter using oAuth ?

Note :
I am aware that there is OAuth and xAuth, i think xAuth uses a pin verification method. What i want to have in my site is a OAuth verification that doesn't use a pin based verification method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) - stable and active.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

I created an simple JSP/Spring/twitter4j example.. [Twitter OAuth](http://tech-read.com/2011/09/17/intergrating-twitter-oauth-using-javaspringtwitter4j/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Spring you can use [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) which can do this for you.